# Huawei E3372 4G LTE modem in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wireless

I have tried to connect the modem by giving the following command.
$ sudo usb_modeswitch -j -v 12d1 -p 157c
and I add the modem at Network connection and it works amazing but when I tried the same at my Desktop PC it gives errors.
[image]

Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: what is the error exactly?and next time you should copy and paste hear the errors you get on the terminal

Comment: Found Device, search for MBIM configuration